# python - Replace values of keys with values corresponding to different keys in the same dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have no experience in Python scripting, but as a requirement in my project I had to build a code and here's the problem I'm experiencing -

I have a dictionary with below values which comes from a unix script to set common paths which I've to read in python -

```
{'# blah blah blah ': '', 'START_DIR': '/PATH/TO/StartDir', 'FIRST_DIR': '${START_DIR}/FirstDir', '# GIBBERISH': 'MORE GIBBERISH', 'SECOND_DIR': '${FIRST_DIR}/SecondDir'....so on and so forth}
```

I was able to read the values but the values would be like -

```
FIRST_DIR="${START_DIR}/FirstDir"
SECOND_DIR="${FIRST_DIR}/SecondDir"
.....
```

As the unix variables don't expand while being read in Python and I want replace the values in the dictionary for all the ${} enclosed variables in values of dict like below -

```
{'# blah blah blah ': '', 'START_DIR': '/PATH/TO/StartDir', 'FIRST_DIR': '/PATH/TO/StartDir/FirstDir', '# GIBBERISH': 'MORE GIBBERISH', 'SECOND_DIR': '/PATH/TO/StartDir/FirstDir/SecondDir'....so on and so forth}
```

I've searched this forum and the closest answer I got is found at this link - https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/80273/replace-keys-in-values-with-key-values-from-same-dictionary 
but I was not able make it work for my problem. Could anyone of you please help me out?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `re.search` to find a unix style variable. If you find a match, replace that variable with the one from your dictionary. The `while` loop is because these variables can refer to variables that have more variables, etc. So continue until all variables have been expanded.

```
import re
def convert_dict(d):
    while any(re.search('\${(.*)}', i) for i in d.values()):
        for key, value in d.items():
            match = re.search('\${(.*)}', value)
            if match:
                d[key] = value.replace(match.group(0), d[match.group(1)])
```

Output

```
>>> d = {'FIRST_DIR': '${START_DIR}/FirstDir',
         '# GIBBERISH': 'MORE GIBBERISH',
         '# blah blah blah ': '',
         'SECOND_DIR': '${FIRST_DIR}/SecondDir',
         'START_DIR': '/PATH/TO/StartDir'}
>>> convert_dict(d)
{'FIRST_DIR': '/PATH/TO/StartDir/FirstDir',
 'START_DIR': '/PATH/TO/StartDir',
 '# blah blah blah ': '',
 '# GIBBERISH': 'MORE GIBBERISH',
 'SECOND_DIR': '/PATH/TO/StartDir/FirstDir/SecondDir'}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton Cory!! It worked perfectly fine. But can you please explain what's happening in the line - `d[key] = value.replace(match.group(0), d[match.group(1)]) ?` I am not able to understand this replacement.